# Firebase onVerificationCompleted is not getting called in latest versions

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase Auth and my sign in provider is Phone .OTP flow was working fine in older version but after upgrading firebase auth version to 20.0.2  and targetSDk version to 29, onVerificationCompleted is not getting called because of this OTP auto retrieval is also not working . Implemented all steps using official [Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth)

Older version :

**implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.4.0'**

**targetSdkVersion 28**

Current version:

**implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:20.0.2'**

**targetSdkVersion 29**

```
private void initializeFirebaseAuth() {

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

        @Override
        public void onVerificationCompleted(@NonNull PhoneAuthCredential credential) {

            Log.e(TAG, "onVerificationCompleted called :");
            showToast("OnVerificationCompleted Called");

            String code = credential.getSmsCode();

            if (code != null && !code.equals("")) {

                Log.e(TAG, "onVerificationCompleted: code auto retrieval " + code);

                etOtp.setText(code);
            }

            mVerificationInProgress = false;
            //show Progress bar
            signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationFailed(@NonNull FirebaseException e) {

            mVerificationInProgress = false;
            Log.e(TAG, "onVerificationFailed   " + e);
            showToast("onVerificationFailed :  " + e);


        }

        @Override
        public void onCodeSent(@NonNull String verificationId, @NonNull PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token) {
            // The SMS verification code has been sent to the provided phone number, we
            // now need to ask the user to enter the code and then construct a credential
            // by combining the code with a verification ID.

            Log.e(TAG, "onCodeSent:" + verificationId + "," + token);
            showToast("OTP has been sent");

            // Save verification ID and resending token so we can use them later
            mVerificationId = verificationId;
            mResendToken = token;

        }


        @Override
        public void onCodeAutoRetrievalTimeOut(@NonNull String s) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onCodeAutoRetrievalTimeOut  " + s);
            super.onCodeAutoRetrievalTimeOut(s);
        }
    };
}
```

Test cases :

[image: Test cases]

Comment: Hey Himanshi Thakur, did you find the solution to this?

Comment: The issue was on the firebase end, it's working now. I didn't change anything in the code just updated my google play services.

Comment: Oh ok cool got it

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable Google Play Integrity API and Device Verification API (currently deprecated) from google cloud console -> https://console.cloud.google.com/home ... it worked for me....